# what is this "->" symbol called name?

Tags: php, symbols

What is this -> symbol Called in PHP. I know it can be interpreted as Equal Sign Right Angle Bracket. | can be called Pipe or OR. but my prof was asking the other term to call the -> symbol. It is for assigning a value to a key in array class. does anyone know what this is called?

Comment: how to call this symbol name?

Comment: _"It is for assigning a value to a key in array class"_ - No it isn't. `->` is used for accessing a class method or property. `=>` is for assigning value in an array. Those are two completely different things used in completely different scenarios.

Comment: Ok.
thanks for your answer

Comment: Ok. thanks for your answer

Comment: "->:" its actual name is "object operator". In 2008 in an opensource linux meet conducted in Hyderabad we proposed a name as "calls". So that wlike writing code we can pronounce $class calls object/property etc. For eg, $class->abc() can be pronounced as $class calls abc().

Ever since we are using that name(calls) unofficially.

Answer (score 0):

This is called the *Object Operator*. It is used to access properties and methods inside a class, where you put the `->` symbol after.

Example from the documentation:

```
<?php
class foo
{
    function do_foo()
    {
        echo "Doing foo."; 
    }
}

$bar = new foo;
$bar->do_foo();
?>
```

As you can see, the `do_foo()` method is located in the `foo` class. To access the method outside the class, you need to use the `->` symbol to access the properties or methods inside the given class.

---

Information from the [PHP documentation](https://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> Within class methods non-static properties may be accessed by using `->` (Object Operator): `$this->property` (where property is the name of the property). Static properties are accessed by using the *::* (Double Colon): `self::$property`. See [Static Keyword](https://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) for more information on the difference between static and non-static properties.

Comment: Can you provide an official reference for the operator's name?

Comment: @axiac As far as I can find on the internet, there is no _official_ resource about the `->` symbol (Object Operator) itself. Thats why I mentioned the documentation about objects, because that is the closest information about the symbol.

Comment: The PHP website (http://www.php.net) **is** the official source of truth regarding PHP. It seems they indeed name `->` as the "Object Operator": http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've mentioned the PHP website as resource. I meant to say with "no official resource" that there is no page about this specific operator. I have updated my answer.